# Error with join statement

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble understanding the error code. I'm grabbing the customer name from the clients tables, then I want to grab the cid where bid is from the branches table, then I'm trying to group the branches_services.sid and the services.sid by the bid in the branches_services table so i can find what customers in the services table have a service fee grater than 2000.

```
select cname from clients where cid in 
(select cid from branches where bid in (select branches_services.sid, services.sid 
from branches_services, services 
where branches_services.sid=services.sid group by bid having sum(sfee) >= 2000));
```

ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Hint:  You have a subquery that returns more than one column.

Comment: You should select one column that is matching to cid in this part "select branches_services.sid, services.sid"

Comment: @GordonLinoff But, I don't understand. In the sub query I want to select `branches_Services.sid from branches_services` and, `services.sid from services` so `where branches_services.sid = services.sid group by bid` because there is more than one bid in the branches_services table. And then I can find people with more than $2000 worth of service fees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your subqueries is returning two columns, but you are using just one value to check if it is found in the pair of values returned. Here:

```
....bid in (select branches_services.sid, services.sid 
from branches_services, services ...
```

So assuming the branches_services table has a column `bid` the query should be:

```
select cname from clients 
where cid in 
(select cid from branches 
   where bid in 
    (select branches_services.bid from branches_services join services 
     on branches_services.sid=services.sid 
     group by bid
     having sum(sfee)>=2000));
```

Comment: `select cname from clients where cid in (select cid from branches where bid in (select branches_services.bid from branches_services, services where branches_services.sid = services.sid group by bid having sum(sfee) >= 2000));` This works also @cdaiga